# What does the 'Play in Starships' button do?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In the game menu of *Civilization: Beyond Earth*, there is an option labelled 'Play in starships'. It appears to be disabled.

[image: Game menu of Civ: Beyond Earth (press esc)]

I know there is a game titled *Sid Meier's Starships* - does this have anything to do with it?

**What is this button, what does it do, and how can I unlock/click it?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- You need to own and install both Civ:BE and Starships
- You need to login to your 2K Account on both games, so they are registered there
- After winning a game press "one more turn"
- The Play in Starships button should now be usable and will transfer your save to Starships
- This allows you to start a Starships game with several bonuses.

Here is a list detailling all the possible bonuses: [Civ-Wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Unlockables_%28CivBE_and_Starships%29)

The hybrid affinities essentially grant you the abilities of both, so they are much stronger than the basic affinities you can pick in Starships.

Comment: So basically it gives you an advantage in Starships?

Comment: Does Steam account work as well?

Comment: Angus: Yes, This also works vice versa, I.e. you can unlock new things in Civ: Be by playing Starships. I updated the answer with a link to a wiki-page detailing the bonuses. @AntoineHejlík As far as I know, only the 2K Account works.